# Issue with none UTF8 characters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have been getting some console errors (20+) complaining about an inaccessible /missing function:

```
TypeError: gridContainer.cubeportfolio is not a function
```

I figured this is another issue with having to require my 'unorthodox' *js* folder so I have added  the following to my `application.js` file:

```
//= require_tree ../plugins/cube-portfolio/
//= require_tree ../plugins
```

Now the error I am getting is:

```
"\xEA" followed by "s" on UTF-8
```

And the extracted source error shows the page stopping on the second line in this script block:

```
    $(".forms-wrapper").backstretch([
        "<%= image_path('bg/3.jpg') %>",
        "<%= image_path('bg/7.jpg') %>",
        "<%= image_path('bg/16.jpg') %>",
        ], {
```

As an experiment I tried removing the following from my application.html.erb but this didn't work.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I suspect it is some sort of inadmissible character in the new *js* files.
I am now loading but there are lots of them.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Most probably you haven't imported all the files needed to make the library work, or maybe not in the needed order, try solving the console problems from top to bottom, or try using CDN's to see if it works well with Rails.

Comment: I think it is related to a file containing the characters 'ês' and so I have grepped for these. I can find a couple of binarys for images, one for an HTML file and one for a file in sprockets .cache file.  Can't see anything in the corresponding source though!

Comment: I have now required the individual files and instead of require_tree. This error has now gone away but I still have the 20+  gridContainer errors.

Comment: Do you have a repository? To see what can I do?

Comment: I can make a Git repo pretty quickly. Your help would be mush appreciated. I am using this as a learning exercise but I am now stuck.

Comment: Git repo added - https://github.com/DunnyOnRails/devise_app. The page in question in sign_up.html. The issues I am having are with the 20+ console errors and the style switcher gives errors.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma just checking you saw my Git repo link?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't had time, try with [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vnhnhm/57d4a4d450d829e0e7e7d1b1b5183647/raw/60901dd27559e50b11a067351adb1ce8e00d31d0/application.js) as your `app/assets/javascript/application.js` file.

Comment: Thanks @SebastiánPalma - I already have this in application.js - the issue is with cubeportfolio.

Comment: I've seen you've added all the cubeportfolio files, but you have the `require_tree .` in the `application.js` file, so, it'll include all the files in the javascripts folder tree. Maybe you were adding twice the things, is it working normally? because I've tested just on the view you said `sign_up`.

Comment: The cubeportfolio files are not in assets/javascripts though, they are in assets/js/subfolders and the plugins folder. The sign_up view is the only one I have imported so far.